# How to export to a CSV selected meta fields in woocommerce and not all metas

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have added two extra meta fields in my inventory tab in woocommerce.

I would like  when I export my products, to be able to select these two meta fields or to have them automatically added in my exported csv file.

Is this possible?

The following is the part of creating my meta field

```
// Display Fields using WooCommerce Action Hook
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_inventory_product_data', 
'woocom_inventory_product_data_custom_field' );

// Hook to save the data value from the custom fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 
'woocom_save_inventory_proddata_custom_field' );

/** Hook callback function to save custom fields information */
function woocom_save_inventory_proddata_custom_field( $post_id ) {

// Save Text Field
$text_field = $_POST['_text_field'];
if( ! empty( $text_field ) ) {
 update_post_meta( $post_id, '_text_field', esc_attr( $text_field ) );
}

}

function woocom_inventory_product_data_custom_field() {
// Create a custom text field

// Text Field
woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
array( 
  'id' => '_text_field', 
  'label' => __( 'My Info', 'woocommerce' ), 
  'placeholder' => 'My Info',
  'desc_tip' => 'true',
  'description' => __( 'Input value.', 'woocommerce' ) 
  )
);
}
```

Comment: yes everything is possible, and if you need help here you need to mention the code which you are using to export the product

Comment: Open Products>Export on top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can based on the WooCommerce Product CSV Importer & Exporter
 Documentation you can use the following hooks:

```
/**
 * Add the custom column to the exporter and the exporter column menu.
 *
 * @param array $columns
 * @return array $columns
 */
function add_export_column( $columns ) {

    // column slug => column name
    $columns['custom_column'] = 'Custom Column';

    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_export_column_names', 'add_export_column' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_export_product_default_columns', 'add_export_column' );

/**
 * Provide the data to be exported for one item in the column.
 *
 * @param mixed $value (default: '')
 * @param WC_Product $product
 * @return mixed $value - Should be in a format that can be output into a text file (string, numeric, etc).
 */
function add_export_data( $value, $product ) {
    $value = $product->get_meta( 'custom_column', true, 'edit' );
    return $value;
}
// Filter you want to hook into will be: 'woocommerce_product_export_product_column_{$column_slug}'.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_export_product_column_custom_column', 'add_export_data', 10, 2 );
```

[Reference](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Product-CSV-Importer-&-Exporter#adding-custom-export-columns-developers)

Comment: custom_column should be the id of the column e.g. _text_field? or meta:_text_field?

Comment: It returns nothing when I replace custom_column,  with _text_field which is the id of my text field

Comment: i will test it locally

Comment: i just test it locally and it's working fine if you need further help please post your custom filed code along with this code to take look again and see what's happening with you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178916/discussion-between-kashalo-and-miaoulis-nikos).

Comment: is there any way to change existing column value? like i want to change regular price column value in CSV file. kindly suggest hook for change value in existing default column @kashalo

Comment: i have changed in get_column_value_regular_price function in this woocommerce/includes/export/class-wc-product-csv-exporter.php file but nothing